# MySQL Function to Select Random Rows and Concat

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table 'word' with id and word as columns. There are 10000 rows with random data in the word field.

I am trying to write a function to select  800 random rows(word fields), from this table and concatenate them.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS generate_messages;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION generate_messages() RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
DECLARE message TEXT;
DECLARE messages TEXT;
DECLARE i INT;
SET message = '';
SET i = 1;
WHILE i < 800 DO
set message = SELECT word FROM word ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
SET message = CONCAT(message,' ');
SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
RETURN message;
END $$;
```

But on running this, I am getting SQL Error 1064, stating Error near SELECT.
I also tried using,

```
SELECT word into message FROM word ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT1;
```

But ended up getting the same error.

Can someone help me where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it should be limit 1 (there is a space between limit and 1)

Comment: @e4c5 , Hey my bad, that's just a typo here.